# how to write one and two dimensional array into a text file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, printf

I want to write each elements of arrays into a text file. Eg below will demonstrate more clearly

```
String[] Name = {"Eric","Matt","Dave"}

Int[] Scores = {[45,56,59,74],[43,67,77,97],[56,78,98,87]}

double[] average = {45.7,77.3,67.4}
```

I want the following in the text file

```
Student Eric scored 45,56,59,74 with average of 45.7
Student Matt scored 43,67,77,97 with average of 77.3
Student Dave scored 56,78,98,87 with average of 67.4
```

I created output file

```
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("output.txt"));
```

I used a for loop

```
for(int i =0;i<=Name.length;i++){

    output.println("Student  " + Name[i] + " scored " + Scores[i] + " with average of " + average[i]);
}
```

But this did not work. Please help.

Comment: Please tell us in what specific way "it did not work".

Comment: Why didn't it work? What happened?

Comment: `Int` with uppercase is not regular java.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the compiler didn't like this line:

```
Int[] Scores = {[45,56,59,74],[43,67,77,97],[56,78,98,87]}
```

There is not an `Int` type in Java. Assuming you mean `int`, the compiler will still complain because `[45,56,59,74]` is not an int!

What you need is an `int[][]` and a declaration like: `{{45,56,59,74}}`

Still, I'm not sure you will be happy with the output...

Comment: `Arrays.toString(int[])` would fix the input easily.

Answer (score 0):

1. two-dimensional arrays need two brackets instead of one,
2. Int should be lower-case,
3. variables should be lower case (scores instead of Scores).

so it should look like this:

```
int[][] scores = {{45,56,59,74},{43,67,77,97},{56,78,98,87}};
```

also, the for-loop should run from 0 to one less than length or else you'll go out of bounds.

```
names.length = 3
names[0] = "Eric"
names[1] = "Matt"
names[2] = "Dave"
```

so, when you try to access names[3], you'll get an out-of-bounds exception because the array only contains 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot to flush or close the PrintStream (I also fixed the errors mentioned above)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] Name = {"Eric","Matt","Dave"};

        int[][] Scores = {{45,56,59,74},{43,67,77,97},{56,78,98,87}};

        double[] average = {45.7,77.3,67.4};



        try (
                PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("output.txt"));
            ){

            for(int i =0;i<Name.length;i++){
                String sc ="";
                for (int j=0;j<Scores[i].length;j++){
                        sc+=Scores[i][j]+" ";
                }
                output.println("Student  " + Name[i] + " scored " + sc + " with average of " + average[i]);
            }
            output.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

note that this is java7 syntax (the try..catch block with the `()` )

see: http://blog.sanaulla.info/2011/07/10/java-7-project-coin-try-with-resources-explained-with-examples/

Answer (score -1):

You must use the FileWriter instead of the PrintStream.

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
                                        "C:/new.txt"), true));

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

for(int i =0;i<=Name.length;i++){
    sb.append("Student " + Name[i] + " scored " + Scores[i]
    + " with average of " + average[i] + "\n"); 
}

bw.write(sb.toString());
bw.close();
```

Comment: instead of "/n" is backslash to insert in a new line. I don't know where that character is on the keyboard of my new machine.

Comment: that does not mean that using buffered writer is a bad answer or solution then.